# prevent html special characters

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to deploy my bookmarklet in public, but I am not sure what is the best way to do it. Suppose I have,

`javascript:(function(){console.log("hello");}())`

And I make it draggable to the bookmarklet by enclosing it within a href tag. The trouble is that HTML special characters are encoded like `%07d` for the above snippet. What's the conventional way to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you wondering how to encode your bookmarklet, or is it being encoded (and if so how, when?) and that is breaking your bookmarklet?

Comment: What makes you think that URL escaping special characters when you turn your JS program in to a `javascript:` scheme URI is actually a problem?

Comment: Thanks! But the error I get with the escaped special characters included in my bookmarklet is this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input What might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine, till it is in the following format.

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){alert('hello');}())">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Note: I changed `console.log()` to `alert()` to make the result view able immediately.

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qyL4L/